# What would be the best approach for calculating the days between two datetime objects or strings?

Tags: javascript

I have an application which allows users to book holidays/absences off from work. It currently only allows date inputs and stores the dates as date objects in the database. However, I need to add the ability for users to book half days. I currently use the [moment-business-days](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-business-days) package in order to calculate the amount of holidays to take/give back to the user.

One idea off the top of my head would be to create two new fields for the start_time and end_time and only allow the user to select either 8:00 or 12:00 for the start time and either 12:00 or 17:00 for the end time. I would then do something like the following below to calculate the total amount taken:

```
const m1 = moment('{admission}', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm'); 
const m2 = moment('{discharge}', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm'); 
const m3 = m2.diff(m1,'minutes'); 

const numdays = Math.floor(m3 / 1440); 
const numhours = Math.floor((m3 % 1440) / 60); 
const numminutes = Math.floor((m3 % 1440) % 60); 
const total = numdays + " day(s) " + numhours +"h " + numminutes +"m";
```

However, as you can see this will output the total days, hours and minutes. I need the output to be either a whole number or .5 (e.g 5 or 5.5)

Can anyone think of any better solutions?

Comment: Don't look at hours / minutes at all. Calculate the days as in endDate - startDate + 1, then subtract 0.5 if start == 12 and subtract 0.5 again if end == 12.

Comment: I wen't for this approach in the end, thank you @ChrisG.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the regular Unix timestamp, divided by 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, then Rounding it up depending on the result. Something like

```js
let date1 = new Date(2010, 6, 26, 11).getTime()
let date2 = new Date(2010, 6, 31).getTime()
let result;
let floatingDays = (date2 - date1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)

if (floatingDays % 1 === 0.5){
  result = floatingDays
} else if(floatingDays % 1 > 0.5){
  result = Math.ceil(floatingDays)
} else {
    result = Math.floor(floatingDays)
}

console.log(result)
```

Of course, you'd need to make sure `date2` is greater than `date1`, things like that